# Writing html form table header to csv file

Tags: php, csv

I have 2 problems/questions i am trying to figure out right now. I have an html form, and inside the form is table. What I am trying to do is to include the table headers that I have in place, and write that to the csv file as the first row. I cannot seem to figure that one out. This is what my html form looks like.

```
<html>
<form>
<table>
<h1> Shorts </h1>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th> Header 1 </th>
  <th> Header 2 </th>
  <th> Header 3 </th>
  <th> Header 4 </th>
  <th> Header 5 </th>
</tr>
</thead>
//form input here....

</table>
</form>
</html>
```

This is the php script that i have

```
     <?php

function myfputcsv($handle, $array, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $eol = "\n") {
    $return = fputcsv($handle, $array, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    if($return !== FALSE && "\n" != $eol && 0 === fseek($handle, -1, SEEK_CUR)) {
        fwrite($handle, $eol);
    }
    return $return;
}

if(isset($_POST['mydrivers']))  {  
$header=array("Driver", "Date", "Customer #", "Invoice #", "Product Description", "Size", "CS", "Btls", "CHK Itls");
$data=array();

$rows = 0;
$fp = fopen('driver' . date('m-d-y'). ".csv", 'a');

while ( ! feof($fp) ) 
{ 
    $stuff = fgets($fp); 
    if ($stuff) $rows++; 
} 
fseek($fp, 0);

//myfputcsv($handle, $header);
 fputcsv($fp, $header);
 foreach (array_slice($_POST,0,count($_POST)-1) as $key => $value) {    
     //$header[]=$key;
     $data[]=$value;
 }  



    myfputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
echo "data added";
}

?>
```

When I open the csv file, the only information that is there is the input data. How can i include all of my `<th>` elements in on the first row?

My second question is how can i save this file to another location? The file will be named as `'filename'. date('m-d-y'). ".csv"` and the location lets say i want it saved on my desktop, would i create a variable with the desktop path plus the file name variable, and be called when using fopen()? The reason i don't have this being downloaded as an attachment is because data will be continuously added to the file.

Comment: You can only pass `input` and `textarea`elements  when submitting a from. Use ajax

Comment: Are the table headers generated server-side programmatically or hard-coded in HTML?

Comment: The table headers are hard-coded in html. Would it be possible to write the headers in an array, and then have that array write to the file? I have thought if that were possible, but i don't know how to code that. I was thinking that my headers variable would be something like this. `$headers = array("header 1", "header 2", "header 3", "header 4", "header 5");` But then i don't know what to do from here.

Comment: @bobdon Yes, I updated my answer below to include this option

Answer (score 0):

Since your headers are hard-coded, I suggest you hard code the headers in your form as hidden variables like this:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
<input type="hidden" name="header1" value="Header 1">
<input type="hidden" name="header2" value="Header 2">
<input type="hidden" name="header3" value="Header 3">
<input type="hidden" name="header4" value="Header 4">
<input type="hidden" name="header5" value="Header 5">
...
</form>
```

Then simply read them via `$_POST['headerN']` where `N` is 1-5. Alternatively, you could simply hard code them server side in an array.

Alternatively, you could simply hard code the headers server side in an array and write them into your CSV file before looping over the data:

```
$headers = array("header 1", "header 2", "header 3", "header 4", "header 5");
fputcsv($handle, $headers);
```

Comment: When i hard code the headers server side i receive an error saying that fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be a resource and null is given.

Comment: Well I assume you're calling those 2 lines of code from within your function `myfputcsv()` where `$handle` is defined. If you're doing it elsewhere I think you're using `$fp`. Try those lines of code before where you have `myfputcsv($fp, $data);` right now.

Comment: Ok, that does work, but the problem is when i enter in data again, the headers appear again. So rather than having 3 rows of data, i have 4 because of the headers being written in again

Comment: I have also updated my code to reflect what you were saying. The result that I get is the headers keep printing once and entry has been submitted.

Comment: A quick way to deal with that could be to count the number of rows in the file, if it's 0, then you put the headers, otherwise, skip that part and dump just the data.

Comment: Could I achieve this using `file()` or `count()`? I am not sure how to achieve that

Comment: Yes, you could use `$fp = file('driver' . date('m-d-y'). ".csv", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);` and then `$lines = count($fp);`, then `if ($lines > 0) { ...add headers ...}`

Comment: I updated my code, and I received a warning message saying that fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be a resource, array give on line 4 of my code which is on the line that has `$return = fputcsv($handle, $array, $delimeter, $enclosure);` Also that parameter 1 on my fclose() needs to be a resource and an array was given.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough earlier. You've replaced your `fopen()` which returns a proper file handle with `file()` which returns an array - that is the source of both errors. I simply meant you could use `file()` solely for counting the number of rows.

Comment: To add to my comment above, add the `fopen()` back like you had it before and instead of `file()` code just loop over the rows using something like this: `$rows = 0; $fp = fopen('driver' . date('m-d-y'). ".csv", "a"); while ( ! feof($fp) )  { if (fgets($fp) $rows++; } fseek($fp, 0);`

Comment: By using this, i receive a fatal error of maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: I think I forgot a closing `)` for the if-condition after `fgets($fp)`, but, can you post your code so I see exactly what you're doing? Also, how big is your CSV files, how many lines?

Comment: @bobdon please consider marking this as the accepted answer if it has helped solve your issue.

Comment: I noticed the closing ) for the if-condition and that is when i received the error message. I will update my code to fit the new code that you added/presented. The csv file is basically a dynamic file. The html form is setup to accept input. So there really is no set size of the file. It is however many times the user inputs information and hits submits. Since this is a daily file that will be created upon submission, The file will start out as nonexistent, and then once the first submission is made, the file will be created and contain that 1 line of data for the first entry

Comment: The reason I ask about the file size is because the 30 second execution timeout could have been a result of parsing a massive CSV file. In which case I recommend moving this to a database. You can also modify the row counting code from above to break the loop as soon as you find a single row, as that's all you really want - so you know whether or not to write the headers.

Comment: I will try to move it to a database. As far as filesize is concerned with, this will note be a massive csv file. I have very little experience working with databases and i have tried looking at it before, but had a difficult time setting it up. But i can always revisit building it through a database